# JavaFX custom dialog set Layout of node

Tags: javafx, dialog

We created a Custom Dialog without an FXML file. We are using JavaFX 8.

The dialog loads and functions as expected but we can not move the Buttons and the TextField to enhance the styling.

1. We have tried to use `tf.setLayoutY(50)` this has no effect.
2. We used this `tf.setPromptText("This Works ?")` and it works.
3. We would rather not use css to accomplish this styling.
4. And we will consider a FXML file if we can keep the two event handlers that force data to be entered in the TextField.

So the question is: How to style this Custom Dialog?

The code is a mess as it includes some concepts we tried:

```
public void CustomDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setResizable(false);

    final Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    stage = (Stage) window;

    stage.setMinHeight(600);
    stage.setMinWidth(400);
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setLayoutX(10);
    tf.setLayoutY(50);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getChildren().add(tf);

    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(tf);

    // Create an event filter that consumes the action if the text is empty
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> filter = event -> {
        if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
            event.consume();
        }
    };

    // lookup the buttons
    ButtonBase okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    // add the event-filter
    okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
    cancelButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);

    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
        if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }

    //Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    //dialogStage.setScene(scene);
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    //dialogStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    //dialogStage.setResizable(false);
    tf.setPromptText("This Works ?");
    tf.requestFocus();// This does not work
    dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this question without knowing exactly what you want the resultant dialog to actually look like.

Comment: @jewelsea Sorry I did not load a screen shot Thanks for the edit I went back to an application we wrote before Scene Builder and solved most of the issues Will post the code

Comment: Since you're using JavaFX, it is highly recommend that you **not** layout your nodes using X/Y coordinates! You should use the built-in [JavaFX Layout Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) control how your nodes are layed out.

Answer (score 0):

Grendel we enhanced your answer so anyone who comes by and sees the code you posted in your question will understand as you said it was a mess
Your posted answer was real old school but less work perhaps than building a FXML file
Besides it is good to know some old school tricks

```
    public void NewDialog(){

            Label lblAmt = new Label("Enter Amount");
            Button btnOK = new Button("OK");
            TextField txtAmt = new TextField();

            AnchorPane secondaryLayout = new AnchorPane();
            secondaryLayout.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;-fx-border-width:10px; -fx-background-color: lightblue;");
            secondaryLayout.getChildren().addAll(lblAmt,btnOK,txtAmt);
            lblAmt.setLayoutX(30);
            lblAmt.setLayoutY(30);
            txtAmt.setLayoutX(164);
            txtAmt.setLayoutY(25);
            txtAmt.setMaxWidth(116);
            btnOK.setLayoutX(190);
            btnOK.setLayoutY(100);
            btnOK.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px;-fx-font-weight: bold;");
            lblAmt.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px;-fx-font-weight: bold;");
            txtAmt.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px;-fx-font-weight: bold;");

            Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 300, 180);

            EventHandler<ActionEvent> filter = event -> {
            if(txtAmt.getText().isEmpty()) {
    event.consume();
            }
            };

            // New window (Stage)
            Stage newWindow = new Stage();
            newWindow.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            //newWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            newWindow.setResizable(false);
            newWindow.setTitle("Second Stage");
            newWindow.setScene(secondScene);
            btnOK.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,filter);
            btnOK.setOnAction(evt -> {
            String str = txtAmt.getText();
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ str "+str);
            if(txtAmt.getText().equals("")) {
                evt.consume();
               txtAmt.requestFocus();
            }else{
              newWindow.close();  
            }
            });

            newWindow.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                if(txtAmt.getText().isEmpty()) {
                event.consume();
            }
            });
            txtAmt.requestFocus();
            newWindow.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: Since you enhanced the answer I will delete my offensive answer your code will more than help anyone who sees my code mess in the question

Comment: suboptimal - why don't you use a Layout that does the sizing/positioning for you (AnchorPane doesn't)? Doing so manually will break if the containing window is resizable. And unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra We are only making a Modal page that is not re sizable Naming convention were created by Grendel he deleted his answer because someone did not like something happy to learn java naming conventions do you have  a class